# React-Native variable as component name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to build an App with react-native. I have multiple Classes and I want to display a class depending on a state.

```
let MyComponent = this.props.navigationState.routes[this.props.navigationState.index].component;
```

this gives me the string 'Scene1' (witch is the name of my Component)

After that I want to display the component like this

```
return <MyComponent />;
```

I'm getting the error:

> Expected a component class, got [object Object].

If I display the component like this:

```
return <Scene1 />;
```

it actually displays my Component.

Does anybody know whats the difference between these two examples? I can't understand why a variable containing a string is not the same as just the string. Maybe I'm missing a very small detail but it I just don't know whats wrong here

EDIT:
as requested my route

```
class Scene1 extends Component {

    render() {

        return(
            <View style={{flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', backgroundColor: 'yellow'}}>
                <Text>Scene1</Text>
                <View>
                    <Text onPress={ () => this.props.navigate({ type: 'push', key: 'scene2' })}>Go to Scene2</Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }

}
```

Comment: can u add your routes here

Comment: updated my post, did you mean this?

Comment: Can you do a console.log on `this.props.navigationState.routes[this.props.navigationState.index]` and `this.props.navigationState` ? And add the file where you define `navigationState`? This error means you're passing an object rather than a function/class as `MyComponent`, which makes me think wherever you set the `navigationState.routes.component`'s, you used a string instead of the actual class.

Comment: @vanBrunneren no, i meant navigationState.routes[..]

Comment: @TuckerConnelly it was like you described it I was using a string instead of the actual class. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I found the same thing, i'm not sure exactly what rules the JSX parser is applying. I can tell you that this works:

```
<this.props.componentClass />
```

Comment: yes this is possible and works, but you can't do this with a complex object with arrays in it like I want to do with my this.props.navigationState.routes[this.props.navigationState.index].component